# Eclipse: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler

Tags: java, eclipse, email

I'm trying to send an email in java.
Here's the code:

```
String mailSmtpHost = "smtp.example.com";
String mailTo = "email@example.com";
        String mailFrom = "email@example.com";
        String mailSubject = "Email subject";
        String mailText = "Some text";
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", mailSmtpHost);
        Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
try {
            Message emailMessage = new MimeMessage(emailSession);
            emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mailTo));
            emailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailFrom));
            emailMessage.setSubject(mailSubject);
            emailMessage.setText(mailText);
            emailSession.setDebug(true);
            Transport.send(emailMessage);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Errore email: "+e.toString());
        }
```

When I compile the project, on line:

```
Message emailMessage = new MimeMessage(emailSession);
```

...the following error comes out:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler
```

Note: I'm using `java -version: 9.0.4`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JDK 9 disables access to many of the javax.* APIs by default, javax activation is now deprecated.

However you can resolve it with adding the module at run time

```
"--add-modules java.activation".
```

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: right click the project. Click Run as then Run Configurations. You can change the parameters passed to the JVM in the Arguments tab in the VM Arguments box.

Comment: If you're having this problem in a webapp running in tomcat, you can add the following line to `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh`: `CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS --add-modules java.activation"`. If the file `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh` doesn't exist, create it and make it executable.

Comment: @LéoR. If javax activation is deprecated, what should we use instead, since it can be removed in later versions?

Comment: I am still waiting for someone to advise how to send email using java since javax.activation is disabled and not available from JDK 15. @Gustavo asked this too

Comment: @MartinKarari: Jakarta Activation appears to be its successor. See the other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61294018

Answer (score 3):

download and add external jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar
Its the Jakarta Activation project.

Comment: Per https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaf/releases/, this is at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/activation/jakarta.activation/1.2.1/jakarta.activation-1.2.1.jar or https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaf/releases/download/1.2.1/jakarta.activation.jar

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error trying do deploy my jar application in a remote server.
In my case i had to download and add to my project the javax.activation library.

Make sure that you got the correct reference of javac.mail and javax.activation library inside your project.properties file before generate the .JAR

[Project.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbcjw.png)