# JavaMail work on localhost but not on server

Tags: jakarta-mail

I've strange issue with JavaMail, with the following code, all work fine when I run it on localhost, but when I deploy it on server this code fail.
The execution stop on:

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
```

The strange thing is that the execution comes freeze on this line, no Exception where launched and code not return or break execution, everything freezes.
Where am I wrong?

Here the full code:

```
package app.util.mail;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MailSender {


    //Destinatari [un indirizzo per ciascuna delle 3 tipologie]
    private static final String INFO_ADDR = "xxx@domain.eu";
    private static final String ADMIN_ADDR = "xxx@domain.eu";
    private static final String ISTITUZ_ADDR = "xxx@domain.eu";

    //Mittente
    private static final String FROM = "postmaster@domain.eu";  
    //PWD di autenticazione mittente
    private static final String PWD = _PWD_;

    //Provider SMTP in Uscita 
    private static final String SMTP_PROVIDER = "smtps.aruba.it";
    private static final String SMTP_PORT = "465";



    public static void send(String type, String subject, String text) throws Exception{
        //Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MailSender.class.getName());

        // Get system properties
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        // Setup mail server (smtp protocol)
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_PROVIDER);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true"); 
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT);    
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*"); 

        // Get the default Session object.
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Auth(FROM, PWD) );

        //Destinatario in base al tipo di richiesta
        String to = "";
        switch( type ) {
            case "info":{   to = INFO_ADDR; break;}
            case "admin":{  to = ADMIN_ADDR; break;}
            case "istituz":{    to = ISTITUZ_ADDR; break;}
            default:{ /* lancia errore */ break;}
        }

        //Encapsulation and than send Message
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        //Mittente
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FROM));

       //Destinatario
       message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                            new InternetAddress(to));

       //Oggetto del Messaggio
       message.setSubject(" XXX ");


       //Corpo del Messaggio
       message.setText(text);


       Transport.send(message);

}
```

}

```
/**
 * Inner-Class for Client Authentication
 */
class Auth extends Authenticator {  

    private static String FROM, PWD;

    protected Auth(String from, String pwd) {
        FROM = from;
        PWD = pwd;
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  

        return new PasswordAuthentication(FROM, PWD);  

    }
```

}

Comment: You [don't need the Authenticator class](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?  How do you know you're not getting any exception?  Your code isn't catching Exception.

Comment: For a more clear and light explanation I removed all the log in the code over. The exceptions are re-launched to the upper class (I've also tried to catch separately and directly surrounded all single blocks in the code over; same results, no excetions are launched on "new MimeMessage" but the code in this point go to freeze).          So I've to remove the Authenticator? Tnx!

Comment: If your application is hung, get a thread dump.  If it's not hung, it must've thrown an Exception or a Throwable.  Catch Throwable and print it out.

Comment: OK, with a try-catch( Throwable [ || Error with same result] ) block on ...new MimeMessage(session); I get a message "javax/activation/DataHandler" with cause "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataHandler" ....With this block, after catching the throwable, the code continue (obviously without sending the email), without the block, the code freeze

Comment: -RESOLVED- The problem is that JDK 9 disables access to many of the javax.* APIs by default, then I need to "--add-modules java.activation".   ---  Complete solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750800/eclipse-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-activation-datahandler

Comment: Well, you never told us you were using JDK 9!  :-)  It's time to use JDK 11.  You might as well use the separate javax.activation jar file along with the JavaMail jar file.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even know it was relevant... -_-'  ....anyway, yes I've added the activation jar to the project build path (and also in the tomcat's lib folder because otherwise it kept on giving me error) and everything worked as it should :)   ...thank you for your support!