# What elements am I missing to ensure mailR Integration with Java via data server runs smoothly?

Tags: java, r, linux

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.createMimeMessage(Email.java:1832)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.buildMimeMessage(Email.java:1268)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1436)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at RJavaClassLoader.findClass(RJavaClassLoader.java:383)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 8 more
NULL
Error: NoClassDefFoundError (Java): javax/activation/DataHandler
```

Is my current error message, I found this question asked prior here: https://github.com/rpremraj/mailR/issues/77

But do not understand how to implement the suggested fix from the comments.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: The link you provided suggests that it may require Java 8. Perhaps see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750800/eclipse-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-activation-datahandler, which explains a way to work around it on Java 9.